SocketIO working on local but does not show on windows VPS
I have a fully working socketIO code that I run locally, when I tried to move it to windows VPS it broke, the IP address (127.0.0.1:5001) only shows Hmm, can't reach this page but opening the Network tab in Inspect shows some connection being made.
This is the token code I use to troubleshoot, I can see that it's running because the numbers keep printing in terminal, just can't open the "dashboard".
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import time
import threading

# Initialize Flask and SocketIO
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

# HTML template for the client
HTML_TEMPLATE = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Real-Time Counter</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
        socket.on('message', function(data) {
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = data.count;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Counter</h1>
    <div id="count">0</div>
</body>
</html>'''

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string(HTML_TEMPLATE)

def background_thread():
    """Example of how to send server generated events to clients."""
    count = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)  # Delay for 1 second
        count += 1
        socketio.emit('message', {'count': count})
        print(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the background thread for counting
    socketio.start_background_task(background_thread)
    # Run the app
    socketio.run(app,  debug=True, use_reloader=False)


I tried different ports and adresses, I tried enabling the port in firewall. When I use curl in CMD it does not show that the app is not running, but freezes instead (for other ports it instantly says that it is an empty port)

The 127.0.0.1 IP address is your own machine. If you deployed the application on a VPS, you have to use the IP address of the VPS.
